# Python Type Error Unsupported Operand

Tags: python

I have a sample program here that is returning the following error when I run it and select an option but I don't see the problem.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

```
#Exception Handling

#If you haven't seen them before, you're not trying hard enough. What are they? Errors. Exceptions. Problems. Know what I'm talking about? I got it with this program:

#Code Example 1 - buggy program
def menu(list, question):
    for entry in list:
        print (1 + list.index(entry),)
        print (")" + entry)

    return input(question) -1

answer = menu(['A','B','C','D','E','F','H','I'],\
'Which letter is your favourite?')

print ('You picked answer ' + (answer + 1))
```

Comment: You may be using the wrong version of Python. In 2.7, `input` will return an integer if the user enters an integer; in 3.x, it will return a string.

Comment: What do you want to give as input - letters or numbers?

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to follow [this](http://www.sthurlow.com/python/lesson11/) tutorial. To be blunt, I suggest finding a new tutorial; this one hasn't been edited very well. The first code sample uses `input`, but the stack trace he claims is produced refers to `raw_input`. Something weird is going on there. And the fact that he suggests downloading Python 2.4 isn't encouraging either.

Comment: I'm at the end of it now, just ran in to this problem. I looked at some similar questions but couldn't figure this out.

Comment: @ webSpider I am trying to take a number in to match their choice of the displayed letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Python3 then `input(question)` returns string `'1'`, `'2'`, etc. You have to convert it into number `int(input(question))`.

Comment: Hi! That was the first thing I tried but I get the same error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Google Drive\Knowledge Base Ned\Learn\IT\Python\Scripts\sthurlow\exceptionHandling.py", line 14, in <module>
    'Which letter is your favourite?')
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Google Drive\Knowledge Base Ned\Learn\IT\Python\Scripts\sthurlow\exceptionHandling.py", line 11, in menu return int(input(question) -1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Its already been pointed out that I should look for a more up to date tutorial so I might just do that. I was able to get all the other examples working except that one

Comment: Not `int(input(question) -1)` but `int(input(question)) -1` Convert input before you use `-1`

Comment: Oh right, I have amended that :) I thought answer would be of type int? I had to convert answer + 1 to a string for it to work

Comment: In Python 3.x `input()` always returns `string`. In Python 2.x `input()` convert `string` to `int` or `float`. `str(answer+1)`.