# Error in python calculator I made

Tags: python, python-2.7, calculator

I attempted to write a program in python that calculates (likely horribly inefficiently, but I digress) using several different operations. However, there was an error I can't figure out when running it. I think it requires defining the type of a variable.
The program:

```
import math
print('Select a number.')
y = input()
print('Select another number.')
x = input()
print('Select what operation you wish to perform. (e for exponentiation, d for division, m for multiplication, a for addition, s for subtraction, mo for modulo, l for log (the base is the first number you entered), r for root)')
z = input()
if z == 'e' or z == 'E':
    print('The answer is ' + y**x)
elif z == 'd' or z == 'D':
    print('The answer is ' + y/z)
elif z == 'm' or z == 'M':
    print('The answer is ' + y*x)
elif z == 'a' or z == 'A':
    print('The answer is ' + y+x)
elif z == 's' or z == 'S':
    print('The answer is ' + y-x)
elif z == 'mo' or z == 'Mo':
    print('The answer is ' + y%x)
elif z == 'l' or z == 'L':
    print('The answer is ' + math.log(x,y))
elif z == 'r' or z == 'R':
    print('The answer is ' + y**(1/x))
```

The error that showed up in the shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/UserNameOmitted/Downloads/Desktop/Python/Calculator.py", line 7, in <module>
    z = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

Comment: Use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: Are you sure? That line number is weird – The error I get [online](https://repl.it/languages/python3) is "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 11, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'". Which suggests this is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412000/python-type-error-unsupported-operand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems here:

1. `z` should be inputted with [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), not `input`.
2. In the division case, you're dividing `y/z` instead of `y/x`.

Comment: OP is using python2.7. So `input` gives an `int`

Answer (score 1):

You have to do

```
z = raw_input()
```

Also input returns as `int` in `python2.x`.So use `raw_input` to read as `str` Then everywhere like `print('The answer is ' + y**x)` into `print('The answer is ' + str(y**x))`

Comment: What about for math.log(x,y)? Would that become str(math.log(x,y))?

Comment: Also, this yields 16/5 = 3.

Comment: if you want decimal answer, do `from __future__ import division` at top of your file

Comment: Which is a better choice? `print('a string ' + str(num_expr))` or `print 'a string', num_expr`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has errors

1. use raw_input() to take string input instead of input()
2. use int(raw_input()) to take integer input, its not an error but it is good practice.
3. you tried to divide int with string.
4. You tried to concatenate string and integer.

Your code should be something like this.

```
import math
print('Select a number.')
y = int(raw_input())
print('Select another number.')
x = int(raw_input())
print('Select what operation you wish to perform. (e for exponentiation, d for division, m for multiplication, a for addition, s for subtraction, mo for modulo, l for log (the base is the first number you entered), r for root)')
z = raw_input()
if z == 'e' or z == 'E':
    print('The answer is %d'  %(y**x))
elif z == 'd' or z == 'D':
    print('The answer is %d'  %(y/x))
elif z == 'm' or z == 'M':
    print('The answer is %d'  %(y*x))
elif z == 'a' or z == 'A':
    print('The answer is %d'  %(y+x))
elif z == 's' or z == 'S':
    print('The answer is %d'  %(y-x))
elif z == 'mo' or z == 'Mo':
    print('The answer is %d'  %(y%x))
elif z == 'l' or z == 'L':
    print('The answer is %d'  %(math.log(x,y)))
elif z == 'r' or z == 'R':
    print('The answer is %d'  %(y**(1/x)))
```